# ScrollTop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, scrolltop

I have an accordion feature that does not adjust the viewport to the top of the open element when it is clicked. View on mobile or small screen size to see what i am talking about: http://startyourlife.com/biz-training/

Here is an example of one that works: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FlexibleSlideToTopAccordion/

You will see that if you click it scrolls to the top of that element. Here is the javascript I currently have:

```
if (section_title.length) {
    section_title.click(function () {
        if ((!section.hasClass('active')) && (!running)) {
            running = true;
            var currentHeight, newHeight;
            items.each(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                }
            });
            if (item.length) {
                item.addClass('active');
            }

            sections.each(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    currentHeight = $(this).find('.w-timeline-section-content').height();
                    $(this).find('.w-timeline-section-content').slideUp();
                }
            });

            newHeight = section_content.height();

            if (activeIndex < index) {

                $('html').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('html').scrollTop() - currentHeight
                });
            }

            section_content.slideDown(null, function () {
                sections.each(function () {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                        $(this).removeClass('active');
                    }
                });
                section.addClass('active');
                activeIndex = index;
                running = false;
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't see any accordion on the first page you linked. -- ETA nevermind, I see it only accordions on mobile, sorry.

Comment: now I can't find your javascript on the page. Are you sure it's being loaded? have you set breakpoints to see if it's being hit?

Comment: Yeah it is working, I just changed html to body and it works better than before but still does not scroll to top of active div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, add this right after the last line "running = false"

```
var target = $(section);
    if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
     }
```